# Способы юнит-тестирования в сложных ситуациях

Tags: юнит-тесты

Интересует, как проводить юнит-тесты в достаточно сложных ситуациях, отличных от возвращения функцией значения. Например:

- Некоторый системный код возвращает набор строк. Надо проверить, что строки те, которые ожидаются.
- Код заполняет контейнеры. Проверить, что в контейнерах корректная информация.
- Тестирование многопоточных приложений. Как это вообще делается?

Расскажите, пожалуйста. Интересует реализация всего этого с использованием фреймворков для тестирования.

Comment: С первыми двумя пунктами непонятно в чём проблема, третий пункт это видимо уже не юнит-тестирование

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такое понятие как тестируемоесть кода, т.е насколько он подходит для тестирования.

1. Это проверка постусловия, т.е тут то, что вы описали в начале - вызвать, и проверить возвращаемые значения.
2. Это проверка инвариантов. Заполнить контейнеры в тесте, и проверить его состояние (корректность информация в контейнерах).
3. Точно также как и обычный, выделяете некий юнит тестирования, и проверяете его постусловия и инварианты.